# XML entity with parameters?

Tags: xml, liquibase, dtd

I want to achieve a resulting XML below, but with modular XML parts

```
<createTable schemaName="mySchema" tableName="myTable">
     <column name="Id" type="int" />
</createTable>
```

I have externalized the xml into DTD Entities

myDTD file:

```
<!ENTITY createDefaultTable "
   <createTable schemaName="${schema}" tableName="${table}">
     <column name="Id" type="int" />
   </createTable>
   ">
```

myXML file:

```
 <!DOCTYPE defaults SYSTEM "myDTD">
 &createDefaultTable;
```

But my missing link is, how can I pass parameters ${schema} and ${table} to be added into my entity from "myXML" file?

Comment: I want to know this aswell. Got any solution?

Answer (score 1):

http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changelog_parameters.html describes how changelog parameters are set. They can be set either with a `<property>` tag at the beginning of your changelog, a system property, or a few different ways depending on how you call Liquibase.

If that is not working, you may be running into a problem where the use of entities is not working with the changelog parameter logic. I think the entity including is transparent to the code using the XML parser so I don't think it will be a problem, but let me know if it still isn't working.

Comment: Nathan, thank you for your answer. It helps me around liquibase, but not around the generic question, how to solve it in XML